# Convert polygon to inverted polygon, i.e. carve out the negative polygon from viewport rectangle

Tags: javascript, geometry, phaser-framework

I'm using this [Line of sight library](https://github.com/byronknoll/visibility-polygon-js) which works similar to [the demo](http://www.byronknoll.com/visibility.html). When you move the player character around it constructs a polygon for the visible area, see the yellow polygon in the screenshot below.

[image: byronknoll visibility polygon example]

However, I would like to get the inverted polygon or the "negative" polygon, so the blue area in the example screenshot. The inverted polygon can be used to block any sprites and elements by filling it with solid black color.

The yellow visibility polygon is an array of x,y positions, for example like this:

```
// viewport 640 x 640 px
// example of visibility polygon
var visibilityPolygon = [ [640, 334], [502, 248], [402, 248], [406, 246], [406, 202], [246, 170], [353, 170], [353, 100], [278, 0], [548, 0], [480, 128], [480, 200], [549, 200], [640, 195], [640, 334] ];
```

In the example screenshot the blue area is one continuous shape, and the problem is that sometimes the visibility polygon will break up the game area into 2 or more invisible parts. I think it is theoretically possible to always draw the blue polygon as one single polygon by using the edges of the viewport to connect any seperate parts. So this can result in infinitely thin lines along the viewport edges but that's not a problem. Another consideration is that it has to redraw every frame, so it needs to be efficient enough to run at 60fps.

[image]

I don't know how to create such an algorithm to get the inverted polygon. Btw the starting point can vary, sometimes it's on the edge of the area but sometimes somewhere in the middle. In the example screenshot it starts on te bottom-left corner of white rectangle.

So my question is, what would such an algorithm look like? Are there any known example of this using just JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call the negative polygon is essentially the original polygon from which you remove the edges on the square outline, which results in one or more open polylines, and to which you add closing segments drawn on the square outline, in the reversed traversal order.

In your second case, drop the edges 6-7-8-9, then close 9-10-11-12-13 with 13-X-9, close 14-15-16-4 with 1-14 and close 2-3-4-5-6 with 6-Y-2 (X and Y are corners).

This is a matter of rearranging the chains of vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I ended up doing is add to the line-of-sight polygon a counter-clock-wise rectangle slightly outside the visible area (because the line of sight polygon is always clock-wise). This will invert any arbitrary polygon. So first find the coordinate closest to the top-left corner, nr 8 in the second example, and then between nr 8 and nr 9 insert the coords for a counter-clock-wise rectangle.